# Read From Files in the format of Longs and Strings

Tags: java, string, long-integer

I have a data file in the following format:

```
1234567890 asdfgasdfgsdfgetsegzdfbcvbsdfg
9876543210 dfgdegdrdatkeqlkrmgda
```

the numbers I want to read/write them as longs and strings as they are. Any Idea how can I do this using one file reader?!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ziesemer's answer seems correct for your original problem and I would recommend you to do that as you have more control in the process. `Scanner` is also a wise option if you are not going to change your file structure in near future...

If you want to write your file as binary use `FileOutputStream` it has variour write methods those can be used for your purpose... See following examples:-

[An Example](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=386)

[Another Example](http://www.java-examples.com/write-byte-array-file-using-fileoutputstream)

[One more example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-fileoutputstream-example/)

These examples are just result of one simple google search, You will get a plenty of them,

Answer (score 2):

Read the file with a FileReader.  Wrap that with a BufferedReader, and use its .readLine() method.  For each line, call `.split(...)` to get a String[] array of the various fields.  For the String fields, you can use them as-are.  For the Long fields, pass the string into `Long.parseLong(string)`.

Comment: Then how can I write longs to the file in the first place?!

Comment: Assuming this is a text-only file (you're not writing the file as binary), you could use a FileWriter, wrap a PrintWriter around it, and use the PrintWriter's various .print* methods.

Comment: Actually I want to write my file as binary to save space

Comment: Your method does not work because numbers are stored as Longs and  not as Strings. And the Long.parseLong(string) works only if we have Strings

Comment: Then you need to be using a DataInputStream / DataOutputStream wrapped around a FileInputStream / FileOutputStream - and not using readers / writers at all.  (Having this requirement in your original question also would have been helpful.)

Answer (score 1):

[Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) with its methods `nextLong()` and `nextString()` and [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) with its `print()` methods seams to be what you are looking for.

To read and write a binary file, you could use [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) with its `readLong()` and `(String)readObject()` methods and [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) with its `writeLong()` and `writeObject()` methods.

Comment: Then how can I write longs to the file in the first place?!

Comment: Your method does not work because numbers are stored as Longs and not as Strings. And the Long.parseLong(string) works only if we have Strings

Comment: Your question suggested you want to write a text file (like the example in the question). If this is not the case, you should make this clear. I will extend my answer...